# R - Apply and remove columns

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply, division

I have a `data.frame` called `dt` that looks like:

```
row.names     A     B     C     D
        1   0.1   0.2   0.5   0.3
        2   0.2   0.3   0.4     0
        3    10  -0.1  -0.3   0.3 # remove A cause 10 / 0.2 > 2
```

And I want to remove the columns such that for a column `X`, if `X[i]/X[i-1]>2,i>=2`.
i.e. If the current row divided by the previous row is greater than 2 (two-fold increase), remove the column.

I have tried `apply` like so:

```
temp<-dt
val<-apply(temp,2,function(y) {
  y<-na.omit(y) # omit na
  ans1 <- y[-1,] / y[-nrow(y),] - 1 # divide previous row
  if (max(ans1,na.rm=TRUE)>2) {
    y<-NULL # remove from temp
  }
})
```

But it doesn't seem to remove the row from `temp`. I thought about maybe returning a list of `colnames` but I can't get them from inside the `apply` with the way I have done it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

=== EDIT ===
Figured it out with a modified version of lukeA's answer:

```
val<-sapply(dt,function(y) {
  y2<-na.omit(y) # omit NA
  ans1 <- y2[-1] / y2[-length(y2)] - 1 # divide previous row
  if (max(ans1,na.rm=TRUE)>1.5|min(ans1,na.rm=TRUE)< -0.5) {
    return(NULL) # return all NULL
  } else {
    return(y) # return original
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert your A values to `NA` (not available):

```
dt$A[-1] <- ifelse(dt$A[-1] / head(dt$A[-1], -1) > 2, NA, dt$A[-1])
```

Now you can decide what to do with thoses `NA`s in your column A, e.g. delete the rows:

```
dt <- dt[!is.na(dt$A), ]
```

This will also work for **all columns** like this:

```
dt[, -1] <- sapply(dt[, -1], function(x) {
  x[-1] <- ifelse(x[-1] / head(x[-1], -1) > 2, NA, x[-1])
  x
})
dt <- na.omit(dt) # remove NA rows
```

And if you want to **delete the columns** with `NA`, you can do it like this:

```
dt[, c(1, which(!is.na(colSums(dt[, -1]))))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to do this for every column like in an `apply`? The matrix `dt` was just a small example, I would be doing it for a very large matrix (think `300x300` and above).

Comment: @Ubobo `dt[, -1]` says *every column but the 1st one*, so: yes. However, `ifelse` is not the fastest. `colSums` on the other hand is superfast. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks, I was editing my comment but it timed out :O! I tried the one with `dt[,-1]` but I get the error `50: In x[-1]/head(x[-1], -1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. And the resulting `dt` is empty.

Comment: @Ubobo I can't reproduce the error with your example data. Do you have `NA`s already present in your data?

Comment: No worries, I got it working with a modified one of yours :), see OP edit. Thanks bud.